# Can I pray for the guy with whom I was supposed to be engaged but something happened and it got cancelled

Tags: nikah, sunnah

Assalamualaikum, hope you are doing well.
So few months ago my family arranged a guy for me to marry. I agreed to it and only talked to him once or twice. He also agreed to get married. His family liked me as well. Everything was going smoothly but one day, without any cause the guy said he didn't want to marry and that really broke my heart and my parents are really stressed about it. He don't even want to talk to anyone about this marriage anymore. I actually like that guy but I can't do anything about it. So can you tell me what should I pray or do so that I can marry him?

Comment: Excuse my, I am westerner and don't know about your customs nor language. What do you mean by "pray for"? Praying for forgiveness on his part, or praying to get married to him?